# Retain array elements containing only letters and hyphens

Tags: php, arrays, regex, filtering, preg-grep

I have the following Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => text
    [1] => texture
    [2] => beans
    [3] => 
)
```

I am wanting to get rid of entries that don't contain a-z or a-z with a dash. In this case, array item 3 (contains just a space).

How would I do this?

Comment: And how do you mean get rid off, if you have [0 1 2 3] and 2 is spaces only do you want [0 1 2] or [0 1 3]?

Comment: I want to delete item 3.

Comment: The reason that Yet Another Geek asked that question (and provided two, specific options) is that "I want to delete item 3" is too vague. Repeating it is not helpful. Please answer with one of the two specific options that Yet Another Geek carefully constructed for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
$input = array( /* your data */ );

function azFilter($var){
    return preg_match('/^[a-z-]+$/i', $var);
}
$output = array_filter($input, 'azFilter');
```

Also in PHP 5.3 there is possible to simplify it:

```
$input = array( /* your data */ );

$output = array_filter($input, function($var){
    return preg_match('/^[a-z-]+$/i', $var);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the data you have provided in your question, use the [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function with an empty callback parameter. This will filter out all empty elements.

```
$array = array( ... );
$array = array_filter($array);
```

If you need to filter the elements you described in your question text, then you need to add a callback function that will return `true` (valid) or `false` (invalid) depending on what you need. You might find the [`ctype_alpha`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) functions useful for that.

```
$array = array( ... );
$array = array_filter($array, 'ctype_alpha');
```

If you need to allow dashes as well, you need to provide an own function as callback:

```
$array = array( ... );
$array = array_filter($array, function($test) {return preg_match('(^[a-zA-Z-]+$)', $test);});
```

This sample callback function is making use of the [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function using a regular expression. Regular expressions can be formulated to represent a specifc group of characters, like here `a-z`, `A-Z` and the dash `-` (minus sign) in the example.

Comment: `ctype_alpha` does not contain dash character.

Comment: Will this work if the array item contains e.g. 2 blank spaces?

Comment: @hsz: edited. @ritch: What do you mean by work? Should two blank spaces count as valid or invalid? Are you actually able to read PHP? If two spaces should be removed, then the answer is: Yes.

Comment: @ritch: Yes that would count as invalid. Two spaces do not match a-z or A-Z or the dash.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```php
<?php
    $arr = array(
        'abc',
        'testing-string',
        'testing another',
        'sdas 213',
        '2323'
    );

    $tmpArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $str){
        if(preg_match("/^([-a-z])+$/i", $str)){
            $tmpArr[] = $str;
        }
    }
    $arr = $tmpArr;
?>
```

Output:

```
array
  0 => string 'abc' (length=3)
  1 => string 'testing-string' (length=14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok , simply you can loop trough the array. Create an regular expression to test if it matches your criteria.If it fails use unset() to remove the selected element.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_grep()` is PHP's solution for using a regular expression with `array_filter()` functionality.

The pattern matches whole strings comprised of one or more letters (case-insensitively) or hyphens.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oeK30))

```
var_export(
    preg_grep('/^[a-z-]+$/i', $array)
);
```

This approach will preserve the original array keys, so if you want an indexed array, use `array_values(preg_grep('/^[a-z-]+$/i', $array))`.