# How do I remove a key from an array if any of it's values contain any string in a separate array?

Tags: php, arrays, strpos, unset, array-filter

I have an array, `$search_results`. Each key has multiple elements. I also have a single column array called `$outofstock`. If any of the elements within a particular key of `$search_results` exactly match any of the entries in `$outofstock`, I would like to remove the key, and re-arrange the key structure, so as to not have a gap in key ordering - and then create a new array of the same name: `$search_results`.

I've tried a few solutions found here - namely

- [Search an Array and remove entry if it doesn't contain A-Z or a A-Z with a dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330748/search-an-array-and-remove-entry-if-it-doesnt-contain-a-z-or-a-a-z-with-a-dash), and
- [PHP - get all keys from a array that start with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979238/php-get-all-keys-from-a-array-that-start-with-a-certain-string)

But I can't seem to get them to match the text exactly and then re-create the array, while using `array_filter` to remove the entries I need to remove.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: My apologies - this is my first post to stack overflow! I've added a bit more information about what I've tried so far. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through one array and remove the index where you find string you are searching for.

```
for($i=0;i$<count($outofstock);$i++){   
    foreach($search_result as $k=>$v){   
        if($outofstock[$i]==$v){    
            unset($search_result[$k]);
        }    
    }    
}

$search_result = array_values($search_result);
```

Comment: I think you're on the right path, but the out of stock goods are still being displayed on the page. Is this code case sensitive? Also I think a small typo at the second $i. Edit: let me make sure the mysql connection to the out of stock database is working before I jump to conclusions

Comment: Just a few changes and it's now working: THNAKS!! ` for($i=0;$i<count($outofstock);$i++){
  foreach ($search_results as $index => $data) {
   if ($data['soda'] == $blacklist[$i]) {
    unset($search_results[$index]);
   }
  }
 } `